# How to insert a variable has html to ionic & angular template file?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic & angular based project. I get variable `node` from a service. node's body value is HTML. But when I print `{{node.body.und[0].value}}` with ionic, it prints HTML codes with tags like `<ul><li><strong>Title:</strong>&nbsp;some text</li><ul>`

Controller and service part of the code:

```
.controller('NodeCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Node) {
    $scope.node = Node.get({nid: $stateParams.nid});
});

.factory('Node', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('some-domain.com/api/node/:nid'+'.json');
})
```

Ionic template:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{node.title}}">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item">
        <h2>{{node.title}}</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="item item-body">
        {{node.body.und[0].value}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

How can I make ionic print `{{node.body.und[0].value}}` as HTML instead of with HTML tags like `<ul><li><strong>Title:</strong>&nbsp;some text</li><ul>`?

[image: example]

Comment: "How can I make ionic print `{{node.body.und[0].value}}` as HTML instead of with HTML tags like `<ul><li><strong>Title:</strong>&nbsp;some text</li><ul>`"  ... I am assuming you mean how can you get it to print as text? Because it is printing it as HTML if you get the tags.

Comment: Or is it just inserting the HTML as a string?

Comment: Have you looked at `ng-bind-html` ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: I have attached a picture to explain the situation better.

Comment: I have changed it as `<p ng-bind-html="node.body.und[0].value"></p>` and it worked as I wanted.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

All Credits to Will.Harris!!

[ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml), is what you are looking for.

**From the Docs**, use the ng-bind-html in the view as:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```

and in the controller, assign the scope variable with the html content as:

```
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.myHTML =
     'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
     '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
}]);
```